# Using Python 3.9 with the networkx package and got the error: KeyError

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

Im using the networkx package in python to cut away unwanted nodes from a directed graph and reconnect the remaining nodes. But i got the KeyError and i cant explain why it occurs. Here some exsample code:

```
import networkx as nx
import functions
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



Path_graph = './Output/graphs_graphml/noPCE/DEXPI_Distillation_noMSR.xml'

functions.plot_graph2(Path_graph, './Output/graphs_plots') #plot function

g = nx.read_graphml(Path_graph) #graphml einladen
    
nodes = list(g.nodes)
    
a = 0
b = 0
    
for x in nodes:
        
        #node = nodes[x] 
        
        if g._node[x]['node_class'] == 'Pipe tee':
           
           newlist = list(g.successors(x))
           
           g.remove_node(x)
           
           a = a+1
           
           for z in newlist:
              
               if g._node[z]['node_class'] == 'Pipe tee':                 
                 
                  newlist = list(g.successors(z))
                 
                  g.remove_node(z)
                 
                  b = b+1
                 
               elif g._node[z]['node_class'] == 'Valve (general)':
                     
                    newlist = list(g.successors(z))
                     
                    g.remove_node(z)
                   
                    b = b+1
               
               elif g._node[z]['node_class'] == 'Flap trap (from 2)':
                  
                    newlist = list(g.successors(z))
                  
                    g.remove_node(z)
                   
                    b = b+1
                  
               elif  g._node[z]['node_class'] == 'Funnel':
               
                     newlist = list(g.successors(z))
               
                     g.remove_node(z)
                   
                     b = b+1
                   
               elif  g._node[z]['node_class'] == 'Orifice plate':
               
                     newlist = list(g.successors(z))
               
                     g.remove_node(z)
                    
                     b = b+1
                   
               elif  g._node[z]['node_class'] == 'Flange':
                
                     newlist = list(g.successors(z))
                
                     g.remove_node(z)
                    
                     b = b+1
               else:
                  
                     g.add_edge(nodes[a],nodes[b])
```

the other lines are built like these. I use the if loop to identify the nodes i want to cut of. And i use the variables a and b to get the indices for the indicies of the list, where all nodes are to reconnect them.

Thank you in advance for our help.

Comment: Can you add the full error message to the question please?

Comment: Yes sorry. Here it is: runfile('C:/Users/Lucky Luciano/Desktop/dexpi2graph_python/untitled3.py', wdir='C:/Users/Lucky Luciano/Desktop/dexpi2graph_python')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Lucky Luciano\Desktop\dexpi2graph_python\untitled3.py", line 29, in <module>
    if g._node[x]['node_class'] == 'Pipe tee':

KeyError: 'Pipe_tee_2'

Answer (score -1):

It's likely that as you're dynamically creating, overwriting, and looping through `newlist` and `g`, you're running into a situation where the loop is trying to process a node (in your case, it looks like that's `Pipe_tee_2`) that has previously been deleted from `g`, which is causing the `KeyError`.

What I'd recommend is scattering a lot of print statements through your code to troubleshoot.  It would specifically be very useful to print `g.nodes()` (if your graph isn't too large) at the start of each loop, then print `newlist` every time it's created (which looks like happens a lot), then print `z` right at the start of that loop.  By doing that, you should be able to pinpoint exactly when the node is getting deleted from `g` and try and rework the code so you avoid the `KeyError`.